# Node.JS getting error while building EXE with PKG module

Tags: node.js, error-handling, build, helper, pkg

I am getting an error while i am building my project and when i build it it gives me these errors which are related to axios module;

```
C:\Users\ardaz\OneDrive\Masaüstü\xxxx\eth-gen-main>pkg -t node12-win-x64 ./index.js
> pkg@5.8.1
> Fetching base Node.js binaries to PKG_CACHE_PATH
  fetched-v12.22.11-win-x64           [====================] 100%

> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\@noble\curves\abstract\weierstrass.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\axios.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\abi-coder.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\fragments.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\interface.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\hash\typed-data.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\abstract-provider.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\abstract-signer.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\ens-resolver.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-fallback.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\provider-jsonrpc.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\fetch.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\fixednumber.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\wallet\hdwallet.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\wallet\wallet.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\wordlists\wordlist-owl.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\utils.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\bind.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\Axios.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\mergeConfig.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\defaults\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\formDataToJSON.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\cancel\CanceledError.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\cancel\CancelToken.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\cancel\isCancel.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\env\data.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\toFormData.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\AxiosError.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\spread.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\isAxiosError.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\AxiosHeaders.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\adapters.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\HttpStatusCode.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\coders\abstract-coder.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\subscriber-polling.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\providers\subscriber-filterid.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\buildURL.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\InterceptorManager.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\buildFullPath.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\validator.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\defaults\transitional.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\toURLEncodedForm.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\platform\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\platform\node\classes\FormData.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\parseHeaders.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\AxiosURLSearchParams.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\transformData.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\isAbsoluteURL.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\combineURLs.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\platform\node\index.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\platform\common\utils.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\fromDataURI.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\AxiosTransformStream.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\formDataToStream.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\readBlob.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\ZlibHeaderTransformStream.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\callbackify.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\cookies.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\isURLSameOrigin.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\parseProtocol.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\speedometer.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\platform\node\classes\URLSearchParams.js
> Warning Failed to make bytecode node12-x64 for file C:\snapshot\eth-gen-main\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\throttle.js
```

I have tried using different node versions by nvm but none of them solved this problem i tried v12 v14 v18 v19 v20 the thing i was expecting is getting a successfull build without errors.